# Convert png images to 9 patch in Android Studio

Tags: android, user-interface, nine-patch, android-studio

In android studio,you can edit 9 patches directly from with the IDE. But is it also possible to convert an png image to 9-patch using the IDE? (similar to the android 9-patch tool provided by the SDK).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well I don't think there is any tool in `Android Studio` but you can do this by `Android Asset Studio`

[Android Asset Studio Simple Nine-patch Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

This is a very handy tool to create simple `9 patch` images for all `dpi` with a clean user interface.

Comment: Thanks Vipul!. Seems like a very glaring omission the android studio. How can we request for this feature to be added.

Comment: @vipul the link is very helpful

Comment: Copy your image and put into drawable folder and just right click on that one, you will get the option Create a 9 patch

Comment: It's possible nowadays with Android studio. Right click on your png, make it a 9 patch and then double click on it and the magic will happen.

Comment: the image created successfully but the image contain black borders

Answer (score 20):

If you rename the resource from `*.png` to `*.9.png` then in Android Studio you may edit it with **9 patch** (a tool provided with the Android SDK).

Comment: @Paschalis You're correct. When I renamed the file manually, Android Studio initially recognised it and let me edit it as a 9 patch image, but it wouldn't compile. The name contained illegal characters, I'm guessing the full stop. CodeMonkey's answer worked though.

Answer (score 18):

Android Studio now has this option available by right-clicking on the image file in your res folder, then selecting `Create 9-Patch file`. You can then open the newly created 9-patch file  and start editing!

Answer (score 2):

Update: Android Studio now has a feature that can be used to generate 9patch images.
To do this navigate to `/home/android-studio/data/sdk/tools` on your terminal
and run `draw9patch`.